# Server accessing two different type of threads

Tags: java

I have a msgs server with 2 different type of threads, one that reads from the client, and the other writes in another client (depending on the receiver)... (and yes, it  has to be that way, I cant have the read/write in the same thread...)

I basically need to store somewhere in an `ArrayList(Server ?)` with all msgs, holding them up until the other client connects to the server.

My problem is:

> I can easily read the object from the Thread, however i can't see any way to extract the object to a shared ArrayList in order to get acess to him in the other thread.

```
--->Input Thread ---> ArrayList ---> OutputThread
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really need is a thread-safe queue, not necessarily an ArrayList.  The [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface is meant specifically for this sort of thing.  Your input thread can put messages into the queue, and the output thread can remove them.  If the queue is empty when the output thread tries to take a message from it, it'll automatically wait for the input thread to add a message.

There are a number of classes that implement the BlockingQueue interface, but you'll probably want to use one of these two:

- [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) is based on a fixed-size array, so you have to choose a size when you construct one, and that's the limit for how many items can be held in the queue.  If the queue is full when the input thread tries to put a message into it, the input thread will wait for the output thread to remove one of the messages already in the queue.
- [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) doesn't require a size limit; you can have a queue that never gets "full", so the input thread can keep putting more and more messages into it even if the output thread isn't removing them fast enough to keep up.  (Queueing up too many messages can eventually lead to an OutOfMemoryError.)

Comment: The problem is: this is for a college project where i'm supposed to use sync and coord mechanisms soo using that would be cheating :)
I just made both threads receive the arraylist and use it for coord, but thx still